# Error : LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item using \textit{\textbf { \begin{itemize}...}}

Tags: lists

why on Latex do I have errors when I write :

```
\section{Question 2}

\textit{\textbf { 
\begin{itemize}
    \begin{enumerate}
   \item A
   \item B
   \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize} }}
```

I have this type of document : `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}`

It's compiling fine but I want ot know why do I have this error : `LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` ( but nothing is missing...)

Comment: What is your minimal working example?

Comment: don't put a list inside \textit or \textbf. These commands are only for short pieces. Use the switches \itshape or \bfseries for longer texts.

Comment: the error highlights exactly what is missing, your outer itemize has no `\item`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have removed `itemize` where I think that it do an error.

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Question 2}



\begin{enumerate}\bfseries\itshape
   \item A
   \item B
   \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is bad style to use a font change around the list but unrelated to the error

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Question 2}


\begin{itemize}
    \begin{enumerate}
   \item A
   \item B
   \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

produces the same error

A list has to have items, perhaps

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Question 2}


\begin{itemize}
\item
    \begin{enumerate}
   \item A
   \item B
   \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```